# anodized insulation and its use as dielectric

Tags: voltage

I've done anodizing before, but I had some questions regarding the anodized insulation and its use as dielectric.

For example, if I want to tolerate a 1000 volt electrical failure do I have to do anodizing with a thousand volts or, for example, with a voltage of 48 V, is this dielectric formed over a long time?

Because in the anodizing two important factors are naturally one stream and one voltage it's good to leave the operation close to zero for a while.
Now, for example, if the current is zero at 48 volts, does our dielectric withstand 1000 volts without fail?